# El mensaje de bienvenida con discord.js no funciona

Tags: nodejs

este es el codigo

bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
console.log(`Nuevo usuario:  ${member.user.username} se ha unido a ${member.guild.name}.`);
});

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu pregunta es muy confusa en su estado actual.. podrias explicar un poco mas el problema?

Comment: `console.log()` imprime en la consola de Node, no envía un mensaje a un canal. Si estás buscando eso, deberías orientar la pregunta a ""¿cómo hago para que envíe un mensaje al canal?""

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que Discord hizo recientemente cambios en la versión v12, y ahora es necesario activar unas opciones para que sea escuchado a los nuevos integrantes.

Debes ir a [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) e ir a BOT y activar **Server Members Intent**, así escuchará a los nuevos.

[image: Activar Server Members Intent para el funcionamiento de guildMemberAdd]